# Rails 4 + Grape Gem + Formatted date and date in JSON response

Tags: json, date, ruby-on-rails-4, grape-api

Rails 4 + Grape Gem + Formatted date and date in JSON response

In my grape response - I am trying to find formatted date in JSON response, but unable to find formatted date.

**Model - Item**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.list_view
    select("items.id as id, items.availability_date as date, items.name as name, items.description")
     .order("id ASC").as_json( except: [ :id, :created_at, :updated_at ])
  end
end
```

**API Call**

## lib/api/v1/item.rb

```
module API
  module V1
    class Items < Grape::API
      version 'v1'
      format :json
      resource :item_data do
        get do
          Item.list_view
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Request**

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/item_data
```

**Response**

```
[
  {
    "description": "Product One Description",
    "date": "2016-03-19",
    "name": "Product One"
  },
  {
    "description": "Product 2 Desc",
    "date": "2016-03-20",
    "name": "Product 2"
  }
]
```

Here I am using [date_format](http://rpatil.github.io/date-format/) gem to show formatted date, but unable to produce the output.
Trying to use -

> DateFormat.change_to(date, "ONLY_DATE")

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date_format'
```

Try include it on lib/api/v1/item.rb